# Requiring DocuSign login to sign a document

Tags: docusignapi

New to Docusign. I am using embedded signing and open the URL in webview. This just let's the user sign the document without requiring them to login their docusign id.

How can I require the user to login their docusignID, before signing the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the your purpose is to authenticate the signer you might want to have a look at [the various authentication methods docusign provides](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/quick-start-adding-signer-authentication.pdf). My personal favorite is using [digital signatures](https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/digital-signatures). Depending on the method you use it may have additional costs.