# User required to sign in before signing document

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am redirecting the user to docusign to sign their document. This is done with docusigns view request.

I would like the user to be required to sign in before signing.
I have been unable to find this in docusign documentation.
I did find this old stack overflow question [Requiring DocuSign login to sign a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654693/requiring-docusign-login-to-sign-a-document) but the first link does not work.

Below is my code for the envelope creation

```
function makeEnvelope(args){

  const env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
  env.emailSubject = 'Please sign this document set';

  // add 1 day reminder
  const notification = new docusign.Notification();
  notification.useAccountDefaults = 'false';

  const reminders = new docusign.Reminders();
  reminders.reminderEnabled = 'true';
  reminders.reminderDelay = '1';
  reminders.reminderFrequency = '1';

  notification.reminders = reminders;
  env.notification = notification;

  const doc1 = new docusign.Document();
  doc1.documentBase64 = Buffer.from(htmlPage(args.htmlArgs)).toString('base64');
  doc1.name = args.documentName;
  doc1.fileExtension = 'html';
  doc1.documentId = '1';

  env.documents = [doc1];

  const signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.htmlArgs.submitterEmail,
    name: args.htmlArgs.submitterName,
    clientUserId: 1,
    recipientId: 1,
    routingOrder: 1 });

  // Signer 2 is the supervisor. Gets sent the document after signer 1 signs
  const signer2 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.htmlArgs.supervisorEmail,
    name: args.htmlArgs.supervisorName,
    recipientId: 2,
    routingOrder: 2 });

  const signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: '**signature_1**',
    anchorYOffset: '10', anchorUnits: 'pixels',
    anchorXOffset: '20'});

  const signHere2 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
    anchorString: '**signature_2**',
    anchorYOffset: '10', anchorUnits: 'pixels',
    anchorXOffset: '20'});

  // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
  signer1.tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    signHereTabs: [signHere1]});

  signer2.tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    signHereTabs: [signHere2]});

  env.recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    signers: [signer1, signer2],
  });
  env.status = args.status;

  return env;
}
```

Here is the view request code

```
recipientView.controller = async (args) => {

  const viewRequest = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();

  viewRequest.returnUrl = args.dsReturnUrl;
  viewRequest.authenticationMethod = 'none';
  viewRequest.email = args.signerEmail;
  viewRequest.userName = args.signerName;
  viewRequest.clientUserId = args.signerClientId;
  viewRequest.authenticationMethod = 'Email';

  return await recipientView.worker(viewRequest, args);
}

recipientView.worker = async (viewRequest, args) =>{

  const dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  dsApiClient.setBasePath(args.basePath);
  dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + args.accessToken);

  const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient)

  const results = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(args.accountId, args.envelopeId, {recipientViewRequest: viewRequest});
  return results.url;
}
```

I have tried different values for `viewRequest.authenticationMethod`
Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want signers to authenticate to DocuSign - they must have a membership in some DocuSign account. You cannot know or check if they do, so this method is not useful unless the envelopes are only sent within an organization to a fixed number of individuals that you know are members of the DocuSign account.

However, there are other ways to require recipient authentication and increase security over email. You can use SMS authentication, KBI or IDV for example. Read about how to use them in this [blog post about recipient authentication](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-implementing-docusign-recipient-authentication).

Comment: All the user do have docusign accounts. I just don't know how to make it a requirement to sign in before signing.

Comment: you do want them to sign from an email, not via your app, right?